# Getting null is not an object (evaluating 'u.default.setString') using React-Native Clipboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

### Question

When I run the following example in snack.expo.io I'm getting the error: `null is not an object (evaluating 'u.default.setString')`

### Background

Here's my exact code which is taken directly from the sample [on GitHub](https://github.com/react-native-community/clipboard#example):

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Clipboard from '@react-native-community/clipboard'

export default function App() {
  const [copiedText, setCopiedText] = useState('')

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    Clipboard.setString('hello world')
  }

  const fetchCopiedText = async () => {
    const text = await Clipboard.getString()
    setCopiedText(text)
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => copyToClipboard()}>
          <Text>Click here to copy to Clipboard</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => fetchCopiedText()}>
          <Text>View copied text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Text style={styles.copiedText}>{copiedText}</Text>
      </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  copiedText: {
    marginTop: 10,
    color: 'red'
  }
})
```

and here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "1.2.2"
  }
}
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library is not included in the Expo SDK currently. You can use `Clipboard` from React Native:

```
import { Clipboard } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much. I was going nuts trying to figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **Android**.
Weird enough I had to do a pod install:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ../
```

after that, I ran
`react-native run-android` and it worked.